# App Engine Messaging System with Message Status - Design Pattern

Tags: google-app-engine, messaging, non-relational-database

I'm building a Threaded Messaging System that will be hosted on Google AppEngine

I've modeled it after the technique described by Brett Slatkin in [Building Scalable, Complex Apps on App Engine](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/BuildingScalableComplexApps.html)

```
class Message(db.Model):
  sender = db.StringProperty()
  body = db.TextProperty()

class MessageIndex(db.Model):
  receivers = db.StringListProperty()
```

The issue I'm having to determining the most efficient way to track the message state for a User.
For example is a message `read`, `archived`, `deleted` for a particular user.

Here are the solution I have come up with so far.

I'm using [Datastore+](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/)'s StructuredProperty to add a state to the message `MessageIndex`

```
class Message(model.Model):
  sender = model.StringProperty()
  body = model.TextProperty()

class _DisplayState(model.Model):
  user_key = model.KeyProperty()
  state = model.IntegerProperty(default=0) # 0-unread, 1-read, 2-archived

class MessageIndex(model.Model):
  receivers = model.StructuredProperty(_DisplayState, repeated=True)
```

This solution, while simple, negates the benefit of the MessageIndex. Additionally since the the MessageIndex is in the same entity group as the message datastore writes will be limited.

[Full Source Code](https://gist.github.com/1025736)

What would be the most efficient way to accomplish this? Would adding an additional entity group be a better solution?

```
class MessageState(model.Model):
  user_key = model.KeyProperty()
  message_key = model.KeyPropery()
  message_state = model.IntegerProperty(default=0) # 0-unread, 1-read, 2-archived
```

Comment: Just how many people do you intend to send each message to?

Comment: @Nick Johnson ideally I would like the system to handle anything from private massages between 2 users to group notifications which will be in the 10,000's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the easiest querying - split your 'receivers' list into four different lists - 'unread', 'read', 'archived', 'deleted' and shuffle the receiver record between the lists as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I like this better, then what I have now. Another question, currently the inbox in comprised of `unread` and `read` messages. Using your technique, to get those messages would you recommend two queries and then a an in memory merge? Or would it be best to merge `unread` and `read` into an `inbox` list. And then using some other technique for read status, considering this is a more commonly changed attribute.

Comment: If you are most commonly using the the read and unread status items together I would, as you suggest, have a combined 'inbox' list, which could still be used in conjunction with a unread list.

Comment: Also - given your response to Nick's question, I would consider implementing some sort of sharding on your message index.